# Flight Trajectory Optimisation Problem

Tags: geometry, optimization

I have a optimisation problem I could not figure out a solution for; this is applied mathematics.

In two dimensional space, there is a projectile at point P and has the velocity V (vector) whose magnitude is always constant. It can change turn its velocity with in a constant rate of w (degrees per second) to the left from the perspective.
There is a line g : X = B * α + T where B is the direction vector of the line (B is 'pointing down' in terms of sketch) and α the parameter. The projectile must steer in such a way that P intersects with g and that V is a negative multiple of B (meaning V would 'point up' in terms of the sketch). Let D be the point at which P will intersect g.

The minimisation problem is that the magnitude of the difference vector of DT must be as big as possible. In other terms, α must be as big as possible.

[image]

I know that the projectile's trajectory must be a part of a circle as it turns to the left by a constant rate of w. The circle's radius r is equal to r = |DP| / sin(180 - 2*β) * sin(β) according to the law of sine where β is the angle between a line, starting a the center of the circle M and intersecting P, and DP.
The distance the projectile must travel is thusly s = 2πr * γ/360 where γ is the angle PMD. The time t that the projectile will need to walk the distance s (which is part of the circle) is t = s / |v|. From this we deduct that t >= PDG / w, as the projectile must be finished turning in the angle PDG by the time it has reached g.
The angle γ becomes smaller as D moves away from T as the distance between D and P will become smaller.

This is where I am stuck. I must somehow determine PDG. I am guessing by doing s / |v| = PDG / w implies s = |v| * PDG / w which implies 2πr * γ/360 = |v| * PDG / w. I will just need a formula for γ.

Update:
Imagine the object turned left with a high angular velocity w, then it will have turned before it has intersected g (and will never intersect it). I am looking for the maximum possible value for w.

Comment: May I suggest making a sketch where *all* the points, vectors, circles, angles, etc that you refer to are shown? It would make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: You are right, I thought of some more variables after I made the sketch and forgot to update. Conveniently, there is one down below.

Comment: It’s still not entirely clear which values are meant to be constant in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object will indeed travel along a circular arc if it turns left at a constant rate. Recall that its velocity is always tangent to its path. In particular, the initial value of $\mathbf v$ defines the arc’s tangent at $P$. The requirement that the velocity be antiparallel to $\mathbf b$ at $D$ means that the line $g$ is tangent to the arc at $D$. Outside of a few degenerate cases, there is at most one circle that meets these requirements. (Actually, there can be a second circle with these tangents, on the other side of $P$, but that one corresponds to a right-hand turn.) Thus, $D$ is uniquely determined by the initial conditions, so there’s nothing to optimize. The point $D$ is easy to find: $D$ and $P$ are equidistant from the intersection of $g$ and the line $P+t\mathbf v$. The center of the arc is at the intersection of the perpendiculars to these lines at $D$ and $P$, respectively.

[image: tangent arcs]

Relaxing the restriction that $g$ be tangent to the path at $D$ doesn’t do anything interesting. In that case, it’s obvious that the distance between $D$ and $T$ is maximized by not turning at all.

*Update:* Once you have the above solution, computing the necessary turn rate $\omega$ (what you call $w$) is straightforward. Letting $\theta$ be the object’s heading, we have, much as you do, $$\omega = {\Delta\theta\over\Delta t}=\Delta\theta\left({r\Delta\theta\over\|\mathbf v\|}\right)^{-1}={\|\mathbf v\|\over r}.$$ The turning radius $r$ can be computed in several ways. The required change of direction $\Delta\theta$ is $\angle{-\mathbf b}-\angle{\mathbf v}$, with $2\pi$ added if negative. With this angle in hand, $$r=\left|{\|D-P\|\over2\sin{\Delta\theta\over2}}\right|.$$ Alternatively, $r$ can be found without explicit angle computations by noting that $C$ is equidistant to $P$ and $D$ and that $\overline{CD}\perp g$. So, letting $\mathbf u=\mathbf v/\|\mathbf v\|$, $R:(x,y)\mapsto(-y,x)$ (counterclockwise rotation by $\frac\pi2$) and using the formula for the distance between a line and point, we have $${R\mathbf b\cdot(P+rR\mathbf u)-R\mathbf b\cdot T\over\|\mathbf b\|}=-r.$$ The negative sign on the right is because $C$ is on the opposite side of $g$ from the direction of its normal $R\mathbf b$. Solving for $r$ and using $R\mathbf b\cdot R\mathbf u=\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf u$ gives $$r={R\mathbf b\cdot(T-P)\over\|\mathbf b\|+\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf u}.$$

Comment: Thank you that was a good push in the right direction. I determined however that there may exist infinitely many circles: taking a look at the line given by P + CP * x, a circle may have its Center anywhere on that line as its distance to P and D will remain the same as it moves up the line, right? So the circle looked for has its center closest to P I am stuck on how to determine that one.

Comment: @univise - When you say "the line given by P + CP * x" do you mean the line passing through the points C and P? That doesn't make sense to me. If the initial direction of $\mathbf v$ is fixed and the projectile must turn left at a constant angular rate and its path must end up tangent to g, then there is only the solution above. If you remove any of those restrictions, other solutions are of course possible.

Comment: @univise There is an infinite number of circles that are tangent to $g$ and *pass through* $P$. Indeed, if you are free to choose the direction of $\mathbf v$, then $D$ can made to be arbitrarily far from $T$. If you are given a fixed initial $\mathbf v$, however, there is only the above solution, as Jens has stated.

Comment: @univise The error you’re making is in not taking *all* of the constraints into account. Although for any point $D$ you can find a point $C'$ on the line $PC$ that’s equidistant from $P$ and $D$, you must also have $g\perp\overline{DC'}$, which will only hold for a small number of choices for $D$.

Answer (score 1):

(It is not quite clear which constants are given once and for all, and which can be chosen by the engineer.)

Choose a hitting point $D$ on $g$ as far south-east as you please. Construct then a circle tangent to $g$ at $D$, lying below $g$, and passing through $P$. This circle may have a large radius. Now leave $P$ counterclockwise on this circle until you reach $D$.

It follows that $|TD|$ can be made arbitrarily large.